# Running an algorithm based on a condition

Tags: qgis-modeler

In QGIS 3.10, is it possible to only run an algorithm in the processing modeler if certain conditions are true?

I'm applying concave hull to a layer, but sometimes that layer is empty and the model throws an error, so it should only run the concave hull if the layer is not empty.

Comment: Purely no. The functionnality comes with the version 3.14 of QGIS (next month). You can test it now with the nightly version 3.13. However I think it exists some tricks to do that with previous versions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I think the nightly version is a bit out of my league (or I'm doing something wrong), so if anyone has a workaround I would be very grateful. Otherwise I just have to wait for 3.14.